# Creating fixtures for model properties of type string decorated with RangedAttribute

Tags: autofixture

Is there a generic way to handle the behavior of *AutoFixture* for this scenario? I would like to customize the fixture under this test so each time I call `fixture.Create<MyModel>();` I get a fully populated model with the string property setup rather than calling `Build<MyModel>()` and dealing with all the overhead each time.

When a model property of type int is decorated with the `RangeAttribute`, it is correctly mocked, however when the underlying type is string a `AutoFixture.ObjectCreationException` exception is thrown stating:

```
'AutoFixture was unable to create an instance from AutoFixture.Kernel.RangedNumberRequest, most likely because it has no public constructor, is an abstract or non-public type.
```

For example:

```
public class MyModel
{
    [Required]
    [Range(1, 65535)]
    public string Port { get; set; }
}

var fixture = new Fixture();
var a = fixture.Create<MyModel>();
```

In 3.51.0 the first call the `Create()` worked, however subsequent calls threw an exception. Now in 4.0.0-rc1 (the version I am using), the first call throws.

Comment: When you call `fixture.Create<MyModel>()`, it should give you a fully populated object by default. IIRC, it takes certain data annotations into account as well. Since you're asking, I assume that this doesn't work in a way you'd like it to, so can you please edit your question to include a repro, as well as expected behaviour?

Comment: That `[Range]` annotation states that the property should be a *number* between 1 and 65,535, but the type of the property is `string`. What does that mean? How is that supposed to work?

Comment: I agree that is odd, but the implementation requires a string equivalent of the property and the attribute itself understands this. Its not all that uncommon in the MVC space, however if I had the luxury to refactor that out I would.

Comment: I don't think this is supported, but you can, if you will, [file an issue](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/issues). It may be related to [this issue](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/issues/678).

Comment: I have created an issue at https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/issues/919